# Table cells resize when zooming in browser

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

When displaying my table in Chrome, the table changes its cells size when zooming in. The table is also displayed in a wrong way in other browsers(IE, Firefox). I've already tried changing the sizes to percentage, didn't seem to work.
This is how it should look like (works in Chrome when zooming is 90%):
[correct table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWiPW.png)
Here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwfgm30r/1/) (how it shouldn't look like)

```
     <table id="Form50_t_data" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: 104.00; position: absolute; left: 1.00; top: 38.50; border-bottom: 0.10mm solid #00FFFF; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;">
        <tr>
           <td colspan="3" id="Form50_t_title" style="border-bottom: 0.30mm solid #00FFFF; background-color: #8080C0; min-height: 9.70; max-height: 9.70;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 10.00mm; text-align: center;">Chrono</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_odd">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">1</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">6</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">14</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_even">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">2</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">7serdbbikguky</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">15</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_odd">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">3</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">8</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">16</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_even">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">4dfghsdftgy</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">9</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">17</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_odd">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">5</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">10</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">18fxgcgjuvfyt</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_even">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">11</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">19</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_odd">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">12</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">20</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_even">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">ghjkl</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">dfgh</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_odd">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">dcfgvhbnj</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">dfghj</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Form50_t_even">
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">&nbsp;</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">cfvgbh</div>
           </td>
           <td style="min-height: 9.30mm; max-height: 9.30mm;">
              <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; line-height: 9.30mm; padding-left: 0.50mm;">fghj</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hmm, the code in the fiddle appears exactly the same as the image you attached, I don't know if it's just me

Comment: I would love to help, but if it's a browser-based issue, I'm sorry that's out of my domain

Comment: `min-height` allows resizing  when you zoom in. Either use `height` or `max-height` and the cells should not resize. And it would be a much better idea to define the sizes in your CSS instead on every cell in HTML

Comment: Maybe it doesnt show because the `max-height` you have on the table styles is exceeded

Comment: @Thodoris Neither height nor max-height seem to work. Nevertheless, thanks for your tip with css

Comment: @Thodoris I've tried to recalculate it once again and I think the table height isn't exceeded.

Comment: @Mark In all browsers I've tried, the last row either doesn't apear at all or only half of it is displayed. Can I ask what browser do you use?

Comment: I use Safari on OS X

Comment: I removed All the `overflow: hidden` from the `divs` (from your fiddle)and the last table cell shows up. But really clean up your code moving all the styles on a css stylesheet. You have so many heights and widths and overflows that it gets really hard to see where you have a problem in your code.

Comment: @Thodoris I have edited the fiddle, hopefully the code will be easier to read and edit now. When I remove the overflows the table gets bigger. Do you know why? Since I have 10 rows of the height 9,3mm and their borders are 0,1mm each and a title of 9,7mm and its border 0,3mm, when I sum it up I get 104mm which is the size of my table, so it should fit the div...

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn't specify `padding: 0mm` to `td` and `margin: 0mm` to the `div` inside. Because of that the `div` inhereted the `height: 104mm` of td and the size of the readjusted to fit div and its padding.